# Add class to the li that contains the menu link to the current page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the menu below and I want to add the class `active` to the `<li>` containing the link to the page that the user is currently viewing.

```html
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
<li class="treeview"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Text</span></a></li>
<li class="treeview"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-th"></i><span>Subtext 1</span><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></a>              
   <ul class=" treeview-menu">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Text 1</a></li>                
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle-o"></i> Text 2</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I tried this jQuery code, but it does not work for me:

```
$(function(){

var url = window.location.pathname, 
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$"); // create regexp to match current url pathname and remove trailing slash if present as it could collide with the link in navigation in case trailing slash wasn't present there
    // now grab every link from the navigation
    $('.treeview a').each(function(){
        // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
            $(this).addClass('active treeview-menu');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Show us what is the value of `url` variable?

Comment: I'm not good on Java and I need to do functional menu. If you can give me a code that works, you have all my appreciation.

Comment: @AdrianEWS what does java have to do with javascript

Comment: The code adds the class to the `a`, not the `li`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. It finds the link which has the current URL as its `href`, finds its parent, and applies the classes to the parent element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href="' + this.location.pathname + '"]').parent().addClass('active treeview-menu');
});
```

Comment: I can give the complete code? As I do not realize what the place to put it.
Thank you.

Comment: Well, simply put this piece of code on the page of your navigation or anywhere else, aslong jQuery is loaded there, too.

Comment: what happens if the page has a hash link?

Comment: Give me an example, please.

Comment: If I'm understand you right, your anchors must look like `<a href="/dashboard">Home</a>`. The function would check the current url with an anchor having the same href. If you have `<a href="#">Test</a>` it's not going to work of course.

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, I have done a number of changes to your code:

- Instead of adding the class to the `a`, I add it to the `li`, as you specified.
- Instead of using RegEx, I use a custom function to remove leading and trailing slashes. (Not sure it is strictly necessary to do this, but it cant hurt.)
- You need to add the class `treeview` to all your `li` if that is the class you want to use in your selector.
- Instead of using the `href` property I use the `pathname` property to get the URL of the link, since it needs to match the `location.pathname` you have at the top of your function. You could off course do a comparison with hostname as well, the point is that you need to compare apples with apples and not oranges.

```
$(function(){
    //Use the function removeSlash to clean up URL instead of using RegExp.
    var url = removeSlash(window.location.pathname);
    //Loop through the treeview elements (the li) instead of the a.
    $('.treeview').each(function(){
        //Find the href of the a in the li.
        var link = $(this).find('a')[0];
        //Use the link we just found instead of this.
        //Also, instead of href, use pathname. That will give just the path, not the host.
        if(url == removeSlash(link.pathname)) {
            //This referes to the li, so we can keep this line of code as it is.
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});

function removeSlash(url) {
    //Remove leading slash, if there is one.
    if(url.charAt(0) == '/') url = url.substring(1);
    //Remove trailing slash, if there is one.
    if(url.charAt(url.length-1) == '/') url = url.substring(0, url.length-1);
    //Return the result.
    return url;
}
```

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r8rcq50d/). Please note that there are a numer of cases where this might not work. For instance I'm not sure what will happend if the current URL is `http://example.com/site.php?x=4` and the `href` of the link is `/site.php`. You should be able to implement ways to handle cases like that by modifying the `removeSlash` function.

Comment: I teseted your code, but not working..... can i help me with another code ? i want to put active class here: li class="active treeview". Thank you.